# Spacing of output and breaking a number into hours and minutes

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm trying to write a program that calculates a preset entry of runners and figures out who's the fastest. It should list the times as

Suzie    329

Phil     445

each having equal spacing, but mine keeps coming out as printed above.

I also am having trouble breaking the final result's time into minute's and hours.

My questions are: how do I make the output spacing the same on every output's time no matter how long the name, and how do I break the final time into minute's and hours?

If you give an answer could you explain how each step works and show how the code should looks?

Here's what I have thus far:

```
        final int numRunners = 16;

        String[] names = { "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie",
                "Phil", "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James",
                "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };

        int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388,
                275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
        }
        fastestRunners(names, times);
    }
    public static void fastestRunners(String [] names, int [] values){
        int i;
        int fastest = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++){
            if ( values [i] < values[i + 1]){
                fastest = i;
            }
            else {
                fastest = i + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The fastest runner is " + names[fastest] + " whose time in minutes is " + values[fastest]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing part of the class. This will never compile. Anyway, I'd write the main loop as follows:

```
int fastest = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if ( values [i] > values[fastest]) {
        fastest = i;
    }
}
```

Because what you have now will not work. As for minutes and hours, you can calculate that as follows:

```
final String name = "Phil";
final int value = 341;
final int hours = value / 60;
final int minutes = value % 60; // modulo
System.out.printf("%-20s: %dh%02dm%n", name, hours, minutes);
```